# What is wrong with my gen_statem fsm implementation?

Tags: erlang, fsm

I am implementing a gen_fsm using the `gen_statem` module and when i am trying to check its state as a `handle_event_function` i get the following error:

```
> ** exception error: {function_clause,
>                         {gen_statem,call,[{ok,<0.139.0>},state,0]}}
>      in function  gen:do_for_proc/2
>         called as gen:do_for_proc({ok,<0.139.0>},#Fun<gen.0.9801092>)
>      in call from gen_statem:'-call_clean/4-fun-0-'/5 (gen_statem.erl, line 637) 25> c("C:/Erlang/Genserv/fsm.erl").
```

Below is my code which is separated into :

```
-mandatory methods for the fsm to work
-api that the client can use (state change,get the state,start)
- generic handlers for when client demands something related to state
-state implementations
```

**Module**

```
-module(fsm).
-record(state,{
    current="None",
    intvCount=0,
    jobCount=0
}).
-export([init/1,terminate/3,callback_mode/0,code_change/4]).

-export([state/1,start/0,hire/2,fire/2,interview/2]).

-export([sitting_home/3,interviewing/3,working/3]).

-behaviour(gen_statem).

%API
start()->
    gen_statem:start_link(?MODULE,[],[]).
state(PID)->
    gen_statem:call(PID,state,0).
hire(PID,Company)->
    gen_statem:call(PID,{hire,Company},0).
fire(PID,Company)->
    gen_statem:call(PID,{fire,Company},0).
interview(PID,Company)->
    gen_state:call(PID,{intv,Company},0).

%mandatory
code_change(V,State,Data,Extra)->{ok,State,Data}.
callback_mode() ->
    [state_functions,handle_event_function].
init([])->
    {ok,sitting_home,#state{current="None",jobCount=0,intvCount=0}}.
terminate(Reasom,State,Data)->
    void.

% Generic handlers
handle_event({call,From},state,State)->
    {keep_state,State,[{reply,From,State}]};
handle_event(_,_,State)->
    {keep_state,State}.

% State implementations
sitting_home({call,From},{intv,Company},State=#state{intvCount=C})->
     {next_state,interviewing,State#state{intvCount=C+1},[{reply,From,"Interviewing by:"++Company}]};
sitting_home(EventType,Event,State)->
     handle_event(EventType,Event,State).
interviewing({call,From},{rejected,Company},State)->
    {next_state,sitting_home,State,[{reply,From,"rejected by:"++Company}]};
interviewing({call,From},{accepted,Company},State=#state{jobCount=J})->
    {next_state,
    working,
    State#state{jobCount=J+1,current=Company},
    [{reply,From,"accepted offer from:"++Company}]
};
interviewing(EventType,Event,State)->
    handle_event(EventType,Event,State).


working({call,From},{fire,Company},State=#state{current=C})->
    {next_state,working,State#state{current="None"},[{reply,From,"Got fired from"++Company}]};
working(EventType,Event,State)->
      handle_event(EventType,Event,State).
```

**Usage**

```
FSM_PID=fsm:start().
fsm:state(PID). //crashes when demanding state
fsm:hire(PID,"Some Company").
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fsm:start()` returns the tuple `{ok,Pid}`. You cannot use directly the return of the function in your next call. Instead you must do something like:

```
{ok,P} = fsm:start().
fsm:state(P).
```

Then you will experience other troubles, the first one is that you specify a timeout of 0, so you will get a timeout error. You will have to change this, and continue debugging :o)

**[edit]**

You don't need to specify the `Pid`, it is done in background by the gen_statem code, the `gen_statem:call` function is executed in the caller context so it still has access to the caller `Pid`.

In fact it is a little more complex, depending if you specify a timeout or not, the `gen_statem:call/3` will spawn a process to call the `gen:call/4` function or will directly call it, thus the `Pid` sent to the state machine will be either the spawned function's one or the caller's one.

The `gen:call/4` also add a `Reference` in the message to the state machine to "sign" the answer and guaranty that an incoming message from any other part of the application will not be interpreted as the answer.

This is a general pattern in erlang (and programming) to hide as much as possible the system mechanism in interface function. Just as you do in the function `state/1`

Comment: A bit unrelated but  i  don't need to specify own Pid when using  `gen_statem:call` right?(in order for the fsm to know who called it)

Comment: @Adrian I have edited my answer to reply to your comment.